# TYPO3 Extension ke_search, results from news and tt_content

Tags: typo3

I try to config extension ke_search. I created Indexer Configuration for tx_news, pages and tt_content.
For Page Indexer, in area "Content element types which should be indexed" I wrote "text,textmedia,textpic,bullets,table,html,header,uploads,tx_news,news,gridelements_pi1"
When I Start Indexer I get result for indexing for page, news and content. So I think thats all good. 
But when I search any word from news or tt_content, in the fornt-end, I have no result. If I search page - I have result.

[image]

[image: Page Indexer]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you set pid in "Record storage page of search data" in News indexing record. It seems to 4 news was indexed successful, so this may be a reason it doesn't find it later.
2. You don't have to set "tx_news,news," in Page indexing. These content types doesn't contain anything valuable to index, it's only plugin instance, so it will index things like header of that plugin element. But no news records, for that you use your News indexing config.
3. Check backend module Faceted search -> droplist option Indexed content. Select your Search Storage and investigate what's indexed for Type: news, does the field Abstract / Content contains anything? Are the pids correct?